# Cartesian product of Hamiltonian graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that cartesian product of 2 Hamiltonian graphs is also Hamiltonian.
Also please explain the significance of cartesian product of 2 graphs

Comment: What kind of product?  $\times$, $\square$, or $\boxtimes$?  What do you mean by significance?  That's an awful broad term...

Comment: What do you understand about the cartesian product of graphs?  I suspect this question is mostly to gauge what you understand about graph products... once you understand a little about what the product is, it will be easy to see that the statement is true.

Comment: By product of two graphs G1,G2 , I mean G1 X G2

Comment: By product of two graphs G1,G2 , I mean G1 X G2 i.e Suppose G1 (V1,E1) and G2(V2,E2), then G1 X G2 has the vertex set V3=(u1,u2), u1∈ V1 and u2 ∈ V2 and 2 vertices (u1,u2) ,(u3,u4) are adjacent iff u1==u3 and u2 and u4 are adjacent in G2 or if u2==u4 and u1 and u3 are adjacent in G1

Comment: What you have just described is the $\square$ product of graphs... not the $\times$ product.

Comment: Oh sorry, please answer for G1  ◻ G2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pair of big hints which will get you started in the right direction.

First suppose that $G_1$ has $m$ vertices and $G_2$ has $n$ vertices.  You can view $G_1\square G_2$ as an $m\times n$ grid of vertices.  In each column is a copy of $G_1$ in each row is a copy of $G_2$.  It will help your understanding if you draw a few examples, draw the product of short two short paths, maybe the product of two small cycles, maybe a path and a cycle.  That'll give you decent enough intuition to answer the question.

Second, if $G_1$ has $m$ vertices and is Hamiltonian, then $C_m$ (the cycle on $m$ vertices) is a subgraph of $G_1$.  Likewise, if $G_2$ has $n$ vertices and is Hamiltonian then $C_n$ is a subgraph of $G_2$.  This implies that $C_m\square C_n$ is a subgraph of $G_1\square G_2$.  Then, all you need to show is that $C_m\square C_n$ is Hamiltonian and you are done (because you find the Hamiltonian cycle in a subgraph of $G_1\square G_2$).  Your intuition from step 1 will help a lot with step 2.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me out